Increase font size in Brave browser
With a high resolution screen the menus and bar are very small and hard to read. I searched in the Appearence and System sections in the Settings menu, but nowhere can I find an option to set the font size.
About: Version 1.67.134 Chromium: 126.0.6478.186 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Please [edit] the tags and add the operating system

Are you trying to adjust the size of fonts in the Brave UI, or the default font size for webpages you are visiting in this browser? Do other applications have better UI font size and so don't need this fix, or is it just that you only use Brave on this computer (to put this another way: do you need ALL the program UI sizes fixed, or just Brave)? Does Ubuntu have display scaling settings?

@music2myear This is a question about Brave, not Ubuntu. I have no similar issue with any other programme.

Scaling IS an OS thing primarily, and only secondarily an application issue. UI font and element sizes are also primarily about the window manager, and less about the application. Most modern applications use frameworks to handle their fonts and UI elements and do not "hard code" these themselves. Can you add the information about the other applications not having the same problem to the body of the question? That is helpful information to know, and it being included in the message body will make your question better.

@music2myear That would be the list of every other programme with a user interface installed on my system. I don't see the usefulness of that. Do you have a particular programme in mind that could be helpful?

Are you saying that every application on your computer is having the same problem? I asked you that in my first comment, and while you didn't directly answer that question, you certainly implied that the issue was limited to Brave. Your question still fails to contain sufficient information and enough clarity for us to answer. Please take the time to CAREFULLY and THOROUGHLY describe your situation in a way that conveys it in its entirety.

To the question "what other applications are not having the problem" I replied "every other". What else do you need to know?

It turns out Brave is missing this feature altogether. Various UI elements of the browser (e.g. bar, menus) ignore the system settings, using instead a tiny font (possibly hard-coded). There is an open request to change this state of affairs for almost two years, but so far with no indication of an implementation on the way.
However, the parent software offers an option to scale the user interface by a given factor. It is passed as an argument to the executable, e.g.:
$ brave-browser --force-device-scale-factor=1.4
This scales the interface wholesale, meaning that those bits of the interface that take actually respect system settings (e.g. tab titles) become rather large. But the bar and menus become readable this way.
